How can I get Hebrew formatting (rtl) for my .rdl report
This is one of many text boxes, and I can't get this to properly format the text left to right.
="<span style='direction:rtl !important; text-align:right !important; font-family:Roboto !important; font-weight:bold !important; font-size:14pt !important;'>" & 
IIf(IsNothing(Fields!new_description.Value),
    Fields!a_012becd95747ef11bfe26045bddffac6_new_general.Value,
    Fields!new_description.Value) &
"</span>"

The placeholder is set to html markup, the report language is set to he-IL (and I also added the language to the text box specifically. You can see by the number of !important tags that I tried to override any other styling that I may have neglected.
What else am I supposed to be doing to ensure that the finished report renders the text right to left? This is for a report that is uploaded to Microsoft Dynamics, downloaded as a pdf.

The HTML formatting is limited in the reporting and doesn't recognize the HTML directions.
There is a Direction property on the Text Box that controls the text.

It should be set to RTL for your text.
